# How do I use tooltip plugin in twitter bootstrap's modal dialog?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, modal-dialog

all. 
i am using bootstrap v2.1.1 (the newest version currently).
i need a tooltip in my modal dialog.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="zh-CN">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap v2.1.1</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-responsive.min.css"/>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("a[rel='tooltip']").tooltip({'placement': 'right', 'z-index': '3000'});
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>      
    <div class="modal modal-open">
        <form class="modal-form form-horizontal">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h3>Login</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="This is a link.">A link</a>        <!-- check it out -->
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
                <button type="reset" class="btn">Reset</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

but the code does NOT work.
The lastest version of bootstrap shows the modal has a z-index of 1050.

and in bootstrap.min.css

```
.modal-open .modal .tooltip{z-index:2080;}
```

This is could not be z-index issue, i think.

anyone can help ? thx a lot.

Comment: Well have you tried changing the z-index?

Comment: like this ? <div class="modal" style="z-index: 100;">...</div>. OK, it works fine. but do you know what ".modal-open" class for ? thank you very much.

Comment: Also this answer helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14025438/bootstrap-popover-not-showing-on-top-of-all-elements/15981951#15981951

Answer (score 19):

Try add this into your CSS file:

```
.tooltip {
    z-index: 2000 !important;
}
```

Comment: -1 Unnecessarily hitting things with the `!important` sledgehammer decreases maintainability in my experience.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you are seeing is due to a bug introduced in Twitter Bootstrap 2.1.1 (see [Issue #4980](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/issues/4980)).  The bug fix for it has already been [committed to the 2.1.2-wip branch](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/commit/88b1e44dd61afd8f08761346555521bd216ed73a), and 2.1.2 should be coming out this coming week.

The problem stems from the fact that the tooltip is not being appended to the `.modal` element, but rather to the `<body>`.  Rather than hacking on the CSS, I'd recommend the following workaround as a temporary hold over until the 2.1.2 is available.

```
$('.modal a[rel="tooltip"]')
  .tooltip({placement: 'right'})
  .data('tooltip')
  .tip()
  .css('z-index', 2080);
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mmfansler/w2CBD/)

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you have done these:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("a[rel='tooltip']").tooltip({'placement': 'right', 'z-index': '3000'});
    });
</script>
```

The above is done. But what about the `data-original-title` attribute? You should give this:

```
<a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="This is a link." data-original-title="This is a link.">A link</a>
```

#### Found the issue: CSS Fix

```
.tooltip {z-index: 50000;}​
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zk7dF/1/

Comment: thank you! praveen. but data-original-title attribute is useless. i tried it.

Comment: Oh okay. What's happening right now? The tooltip itself isn't getting displayed or what? Or did you see the console to get errors? Any demo?

Comment: the tooltip isn't getting displayed. console is fine, no error log or something else. thank you again.

Comment: Will make a fiddle and check out.

Comment: @ZhuoYING Bingo!!! Got the issue! Check out the updated answer!!! :) Is this working???

Answer (score 1):

Works for me:
    { 
      html: true,
      placement: 'right',
      container: '.modal-body',
      title: ''
    };

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do that with Bootstrap3, finally!

Checkout http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: How is this fixed in Bootstrap 3? If you add a tooltip on a button that's in the upper right corner, it still has the wrong z-index even if you specify `body` as the container; so you **still** have to add CSS to override the z-index.