# Bootstrap - Popover gets cut off by modal header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a popover inside a modal window in Bootstrap 2.3.1.  The problem is that the popover displays UNDER the modal-header div.

You can see an example / fiddle of this problem here: ("Launch Demo Modal", then "Click to toggle popover")
http://jsfiddle.net/cZ6Cr/2/

The relevant code is:

```
<a class="btn" data-content="And here's some amazing content.  It's very engaging.     right? And another thing about this is a that it's really long.  When I say long I mean really, really long." 
rel="popover" 
href="#"
data-original-title="A Title">
Click to toggle popover
</a>
```

*I modified a fiddle created by cvrebert from this thread on GitHub
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/5014

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using?

Comment: possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12758872/how-do-i-use-tooltip-plugin-in-twitter-bootstraps-modal-dialog)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed by using:
    `.modal-body{overflow-y:visible;}`

OR

```
.modal-body{overflow:visible;}
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/cZ6Cr/4/

Comment: It should be noted that if .modal-body is longer than the screen height, this solution will prove problematic.

Answer (score 17):

It proves a little tricky to dynamically resize your modal container based on tooltip size.
However, you can take your tooltip out of the HTML flow by adding `position: fixed`.

**CSS**:

```css
.popover {
    z-index: 9999;
    position: fixed;
}
```

### [Live Demo in jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/gDjtk/)

Which will look likes this:

[image: demo]

Comment: kind of a hack ;) but I have certainly considered it

Comment: Actually, if you "Launch Demo Modal", then "Click to toggle popover" you will see the full problem.  The popover text is already on the right.

Comment: This is the right approach: it takes the popover out of the viewport flow and lets popper.js do its job. This answer should be framed.